# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1?

Tags: flutter

my `console`

```
> Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
E:\Flutter Project\perpet1\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-22:20 Error:
    android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

---

my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.perpet1">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver"/>
</manifest>
```

---

So, I did flutter_local_notification update.
Then it appeared on the console as follows.

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

**There is no flutter doctor issue.**

(in Android Studio)
First, I apologize that English is not my main language and it can be awkward because it is also my first time posting questions.
Above is the error on my console window.
I searched all day yesterday but couldn't find a solution. I would be truly grateful if someone helped me. TT

Comment: Looks like you're using an older version of the ``flutter_local_notifications`` package. You need to use the latest version or set targetSdk to lower if you choose not to upgrade the package.

Comment: looks like these are mare warnings, this shouldn't interrupt your app from running, though you need to work on upgrading your project and packages.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still loading if there's any other problem, but I don't see any errors or warnings, so I think the important problem has been solved. Thank you very much for your kind help. Have a nice day!